# Is it "I was assigned to a task" or "the task was assigned to me"?

Tags: word-usage, phrase-meaning, phrase-usage, idioms

Which of the following is correct and why?

1. I was assigned the task
2. I was assigned to the task
3. The task was assigned to me

I hope the first and the third ones are correct but I'm doubtful about 2. Is there any context in which the second one can be correct?

Comment: They're all fine. A task can be assigned to a person (sentences 1 and 3), and a person can be assigned to a task (sentence 2).

Answer (score 3):

These are all correct.

1: I was given a task

2: A task needed people to do it and I was chosen

3: I was given a task (same meaning as 1 but with the word order flipped)

The difference is very subtle and they are all likely to be used interchangeably